# doPostback and then navigate to another page

Tags: javascript, dopostback

I am trying to call __doPostBack from within JavaScript and then navigate to another page.  The script I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $("a.change-link").click(function(){          
             __doPostBack("","");  
             location.href='pageToGoTo';                                                                                            
   });

});
```

The code is not getting to the `location.href='pageToGoTo'` line after the post back.

Is there anyway to achieve this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.href='pageToGoTo';` will never be executed since you're posting the entire form back to the server. You'll need to redirect the request on the server-side.

```
Response.Redirect = "pageToGoTo";
```